# why can't convert SEXP to Rcpp::NumericMatrix？

Tags: rcpp, rinside

I use R by rinside

```
std::string cmd = "m <-matrix(c(1:9),nrow=3))";
SEXP proxy =  m_R.parseEvalNT(cmd);
Rcpp::NumericMatrix m(proxy);
```

the runtime  to terminate it in an unusual way

anyone please help me
thanks

Comment: Your code does not parse correctly, try `parse( text = "m <-matrix(c(1:9),nrow=3))" )`in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odd. I played with this and also got some run-time errors; now they no longer arise.  Try this:

```
// -*- mode: C++; c-indent-level: 4; c-basic-offset: 4;  tab-width: 8; -*-
//
// cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403402/
//
// GPL'ed 

#include <RInside.h>                    // for the embedded R via RInside

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    RInside R(argc, argv);              // create an embedded R instance 

    std::string cmd = "m <- matrix(c(1:9),nrow=3)";
    Rcpp::NumericMatrix M = R.parseEval(cmd);  // assign mat. M to NumericMatrix
    int n = M.nrow();
    int k = M.ncol();
    std::cout << "All good:" << n << " by " << k << std::endl;

    exit(0);
}

edd@max:~/svn/rinside/pkg/inst/examples/standard$ ./so20130823 
All good:3 by 3
edd@max:~/svn/rinside/pkg/inst/examples/standard$
```

which I just copied into the `examples/standard/` directory as a simple call to `make` will then build it.

Comment: I found that I make mistake, std::string cmd = "m <-matrix(c(1:9),nrow=3))"; here is much more a parenthesis,the code work when remove it. thank you very much.rinside is great work.

Comment: Doh. That bit me too when I copied it.  See `rinside_sample2.cpp` and `rinside_sample3.cpp` both of which also use a Matrix.  Oh, and feel free to 'accept' and/or 'upvote' this answer as that's how the StackOverflow site works.

Comment: I was first time to use StackOverflow,I have  accept the answer.thank you again